# Examine all the event subscribers to a vb.net control event

Tags: vb.net, events

I have a situation where it looks like an event is getting called twice.

We are building the control in code , so the most likely cause is that I have inadvertently added the event handler twice.

A simple examination of the code is not solving the problem.

I would like to be able to look at button.Click and see how many routines are added to the OnClick event.
I thought this would be a simple matter, but I am not seeing any property that wants to report on subscribers to the different events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.  There is a link to the original code.  To test you need a form and a button.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim _delegates As [Delegate] = GetEventHandler(Button1, "EventClick")
        If _delegates IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each d As [Delegate] In _delegates.GetInvocationList
                Debug.WriteLine(d.Method.Name)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_FOO_(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    End Sub

    ' from https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?525533-Retrieving-the-EventHandler-for-any-Event-by-code&p=3246140&viewfull=1#post3246140
    Private Function GetEventHandler(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal eventname As String) As [Delegate]
        Dim propInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo
        propInfo = GetType(System.ComponentModel.Component).GetProperty("Events", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
                                                                                    Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or
                                                                                    Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
        Dim handlerList As System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList
        handlerList = CType(propInfo.GetValue(ctrl, Nothing), System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList)
        Dim controlEventInfo As System.Reflection.FieldInfo
        controlEventInfo = GetType(Control).GetField(eventname, Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
                                                                 Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)

        If controlEventInfo Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
            ' Throw New ArgumentException("Specified event does not exist.")
        End If

        Dim eventKey As Object = controlEventInfo.GetValue(ctrl)
        Dim EventHandlerDelegate As [Delegate] = handlerList.Item(eventKey)
        Return EventHandlerDelegate
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: thank you.  I wasnt google the right things.  Much appreciated.